# DELETE row in table, but keep information in other table related to this row

Tags: sql, cascade

[image]

First of all, I'm sorry for the namings begin in Dutch.
(quick translations: TblOntleendetail = TblBorrowingDetails / TblExemplaar = TblCopy / TblBoek = TblBook / TblTijdschrift = TblMagazine)
The diagram you see up here is the database for a library.
Only the tables in the red rectangle are needed for my question.

So I want to execute the next query:

```
DELETE FROM TblItem
WHERE Titel = 'Niets is ooit'
```

Now I don't want to use the delete rule CASCADE on the foreign keys, because it looks something best to be avoided I think.

QUESTION:

How can I delete that specific Item that has as title 'Niets is ooit' (this book is no longer in the library), without losing track of the borrowing history of the copies of this item (which is stored in the table TblOntleenDetail, translated as 'TblBorrowingDetails' / TblExemplaar, translated as 'TblCopy')?

On the other hand, the information stored in TblBoek and TblTijdschrift needs to be deleted.

Comment: How about having a nullable column in TblItem for the date when the item was removed from the library? Then if you want to get all the current items, select them with `... AND RemovedDate = NULL`. That way you keep all the historical data and don't lose track of things.

Comment: @AndrewMorton: `RemovedDate = NULL` won't return anything. You have to use `RemovedDate IS NULL`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Well there goes my 15 points for answering that question that'll never happen now :)

Comment: Thanks already for the help! I'll give this a try. Is it also possible to delete a row in TblItem and keep the rows in TblOntleenDetail that are referring to the deleted row in TblItem?